# How can I get the roles of codec information in Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, codec

In Android 4.0(API level 15), there is no API to get the codec list. [New API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecList.html) only support API level 16 and later. But I have to support API level 15. So I have to use JNI to write some native code referring [here](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/omx/OMXMaster.cpp).

```
struct OMXPluginBase {
    OMXPluginBase() {}
    virtual ~OMXPluginBase() {}

    virtual void dummy1() = 0;
    virtual void dummy2() = 0;
    virtual OMX_ERRORTYPE enumerateComponents(
                            OMX_STRING name,
                            size_t size,
                            OMX_U32 index) = 0;
    virtual OMX_ERRORTYPE getRolesOfComponent(
                            const char *name,
                            Vector<String8> *roles) = 0;
private:
    OMXPluginBase(const OMXPluginBase &);
    OMXPluginBase &operator=(const OMXPluginBase &);
};
```

The code to get the name of the codec information:

```
void *handle = dlopen("libstagefrighthw.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (handle == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
typedef OMXPluginBase *(*CreateOMXPluginFunc)();
CreateOMXPluginFunc createOMXPlugin =
    (CreateOMXPluginFunc)dlsym(handle, "createOMXPlugin");
if (!createOMXPlugin) {
    createOMXPlugin = (CreateOMXPluginFunc)dlsym(
        handle, "_ZN7android15createOMXPluginEv");
} 
OMXPluginBase *plugin = (*createOMXPlugin)();
if (plugin) {
    OMX_U32 index = -1;
    char name[128];
    OMX_ERRORTYPE err;
    while ((err = plugin->enumerateComponents(name, sizeof(name),
                    ++index)) == OMX_ErrorNone) {
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }
    if (err != OMX_ErrorNoMore) {
        printf("0x%x\n", err);
    }
}
```

I can get the name of the codec information since the name is just of type `char *`. However, now I want to get the roles of the codec information using the function 
`OMX_ERRORTYPE getRolesOfComponent(const char *name, Vector<String8> *roles)` 
but I cannot do that because `roles` is of type `Vector<String8>` and I don't have this two class. More seriously, Android seems not provide the implementation of this two class in some shared library like `libutils.so`. So how can I call this function and get the information I want? Please help me. I have got headache for this for a whole day!

**Update**

Thanks to @Alex, finally I solved my problem. I put the code [here](https://gist.github.com/itlodge/7652195). Hope this will help those who met the same problem.

Comment: I like our approach to work with non-public native APIs through `dlopen()`. For all practical purposes, though, you can link directly to libstagefright.so and others, and also `#include` system headers for `android::Vector` and `android::String8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `android::Vector` and `android::String8` are implemented in `libutils.so`.

So, if you can link to this library, you can write something like:

```
Vector<String8> roles;
err = plugin->getRolesOfComponent(name, &roles);
if (err == OMX_ErrorNone) {
    for (int i=0; i<roles.size(); i++) {
        printf("  %s\n", roles.array()[0].string());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my experiment shows that `getRolesOfComponent()` needs a fully correctly initialized reference to Vector, so you need to call the constructor (in `libutils.so`) manually if you want to keep all access to Android private classes through `dlopen()`.

Comment: But I found that the construtor of ``Vector`` is inline, so there are no such symbol in ``libutils.so``.

Comment: Vector constructor is inline, but it depends on VectorImpl constructor, which is not.

Comment: When I do this ``Vector<String8> roles;``, it will call the construtor of ``Vector<String>`` automatically. How can I let it call ``VectorImpl``? Also, ``Vector`` is a class template, not a class.

Comment: Vector extends VectorImpl. You must provide the correct class (ok, template) definition for Vector, because `getRolesOfComponent()` failes if its argument is not valid.

Comment: @Yuanhang please provide more details on how you've solved your problem. Also it would be great if you could provide any samples on your dynamic loading of the libstagefright.so